# The CXF client returns a NullPointerException

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I'm using CXF for my web service backend/client stubs.
When the client invokes the web service, I get the following error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createContext(JAXBDataBinding.java:559)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createJAXBContextAndSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:497)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:324)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:442)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:680)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:505)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:242)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:202)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:90)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:144)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:133)
    at com.amazonws.AmazonWS.createAmazonWS(AmazonWS.java:49)
```

The line 49 points to the following instruction :

```
AmazonWS client = (AmazonWS) factory.create();
```

which comes after the following block :

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
factory.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
factory.setServiceClass(AmazonWS.class);
factory.setAddress("http://localhost:9000/helloAmazon");
```

What am I doing wrong ? It seems that my client can't even reach the web service.
Why ?

Thank you

Comment: if you type in the address in your webbrowser, did you receive any result?

Comment: It's ok : I can have my wsdl when I type : `http://localhost:9000/helloAmazon?wsdl`

Comment: What version of CXF?   Looks like an ancient version of CXF as line 559 of JAXBDataBinding has had any code that could NPE for well over a year.  Try a newer version of CXF.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post want version of CXF are you using?

Also make sure that you import all the CXF xml that you require:

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-http.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/osgi/cxf-extension-osgi.xml" />
```

and try to use `http://localhost:9000/helloAmazon?wsdl` instead of `http://localhost:9000/helloAmazon`